# checking convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{1-2n}{1-3n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to test endpoints for integral of convergence, and this one has been giving me a fit...
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{1-2n}{1-3n}$$

I tried the alt. series test, which was inconclusive, I tried the ratio test, which was inconclusive, I tried absolute convergence, which was no help since it did not converge absolutlely.... then I had the thought $(-1)^{n}=1\vee -1$... so, couldn't I just test each condition individually using the regular diversion test?

Doing so I get:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1+2n}{1+3n}=\frac{2}{3}\neq 0\rightarrow \text{divergent}$$
and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}-\frac{1+2n}{1+3n}\rightarrow -\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1+2n}{1+3n}=-\frac{2}{3}\neq 0\rightarrow \text{divergent}$$

Is there anything wrong with this approach?  It seems that it may be inappropriate since the conversion/diversion of $a_n$ and $-a_n$ may not correlate to an alternating series.  If I'm off-base here, would someone mind pointing me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: That's legit. Basically, your argument says that the tail of the sum (when $n\gg1$) is made of contant terms $-2/3$, which is obviously divergent.

Comment: Cool. Thank you @Abezhiko.  Appreciate the sanity check!  I had to google that "much greater than" symbol, but now I know what that is - so thanks for that as well!  One of the reasons I like this site is like learning this math "language"...

Comment: (@Abezhiko Note that the terms are not all ~ -2/3. some of them are ~2/3. ) What you're looking for is the "first" test of convergence, that a sequence converges requires that the individual terms converge to 0 (though that condition isn't sufficient, which is why we look for the other tests)

Comment: @CalvinLin You're right, I forgot the $(-1)^n$ factor; so, the argument would that the tail of the sum is -2/3 times Cesàro series, which doesn't converge.

Comment: A necessary condition for convergence is $|a_n|\to 0,$ which is equivalent to $a_n\to 0.$ We have $|a_n|\to {2\over 3}\neq 0.$ Another way: $a_{2n}\to {2/3}\neq 0.$ Once you get that, you do not need to test $a_{2n+1}.$ If $a_{2n}\to 0$ for some series then you have to test the behaviour of $a_{2n+1},$ whether the necessary condition fails.

Comment: One of these comments should be turned into an answer.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc - isn't what you're describing the alternating series test?  My understanding, based on what's been taught so far in this class, is that the alternating series test can only tell us convergence, not divergence.  I.e. if $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left | a_n \right |=0$ then the series converges, but if not, then we have to use another test to show divergence.  That's been the problem, every test I've tried has been inconclusive.

Comment: No, it makes sense to apply the alternating test only when the necessary condition $a_n\to 0$ is satisfied.

Comment: @joriki It seems my answer is not helpful. I am removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that it is the sum of $2$ series that don't converge since the terms never go to zero. Here's what I mean. Write it like

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1-2(2k)}{1-3(2k)}-\frac{1-2(2k+1)}{1-3(2k+1)}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_k \frac{1}{ (3 k + 1) (6 k - 1)}\approx 0.457​85$$ and use the new $a_k$ for your ratio test, or whatever test you like. My favorite is the [Gauss' Test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your approach to alternating series convergence is correct and avoids the trap/trick in the question.

A series is convergent if its partial sums have a limit. If some terms don't approach 0, the partial sum will change drastically at those terms, and so, the partial sums won't converge.

The trap is that you can have series where a subset of partial sums converge. Eg if you take $b_n=a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}$, you can get a convergent series.

I believe that's the case here, and you're correct in not pursuing that avenue.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that if $\sum a_n$ is a convergent series, then $a_n\to 0$. This is a consequence of the Cauchy criterion of convergence.

The $n$th term $(-1)^n\frac{1-2n}{1-3n}$ of the series doesn't converge to zero, so no more needs to be said. The series is divergent.

In fact, the analysis in your post shows that $a_n$ doesn't converge *at all*, let alone converge to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If we can show absolute convergence for your series, then the original series converges. That is, if $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{|a_n|}$ converges, $\implies \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n a_n}$ convergence.

Given, $|a_n| = \frac{2n-1}{3n-1}, n \ge 0$, we can prove inverse implication of convergence by $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{|a_n|}$ convergence $\implies \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}(1 + |a_n|)$ convergence.

$$\prod_{n = 0}^{k}{1 + \frac{2n - 1}{3n - 1}} = \prod_{n = 0}^{k}{\frac{5n - 2}{3n - 1}} = \frac{5\big(\frac{5}{3}\big)^k\big(k - \frac{2}{5}\big)!\big(\frac{-4}{3}\big)!}{3\big(k - \frac{1}{3}\big)!\big(\frac{-7}{5}\big)!}$$

However, $$\lim_{k \to \infty}{\left( \frac{5\big(\frac{5}{3}\big)^k\big(k - \frac{2}{5}\big)!\big(\frac{-4}{3}\big)!}{3\big(k - \frac{1}{3}\big)!\big(\frac{-7}{5}\big)!} \right)} \to \infty\cdot0  \text{  (indeterminate)} $$

which suggests divergence, and hence $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{|a_n|}$ diverges too.

Futhermore, $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\left(\sum_{n = 0}^{k}{\ln{\left( \frac{2n - 1}{3n - 1} \right)}}\right) = \lim_{k \to \infty}\left(\ln{\prod_{n = 0}^{k}{\left(\frac{2n - 1}{3n - 1}\right)}}\right) \to \ln{0}$$ Since the inside product converges to $0$, the logarithmic summation diverges. $\frac{2n - 1}{3n - 1} > \ln{\left(\frac{2n - 1}{3n - 1}\right)}, n > 0$ and thus (through absolute convergence stated earlier), your summation diverges too.

Answer (score 1):

Using Lerch transcendent function
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^{p}(-1)^{n}\frac{1-2n}{1-3n}$$
$$S_p=-\frac{9 +3 \log (2)-\pi\sqrt{3}  }{27}-\frac{(-1)^p }{9}  \left(\Phi\left(-1,1,\frac{3p+2}{3}\right)-3\right)$$

For large values of $p$, $\Phi\left(-1,1,\frac{3p+2}{3}\right) \to 0$ which makes
$$S_p \sim -\frac{9 +3 \log (2)-\pi\sqrt{3}  }{27}+\frac{(-1)^p }{3}$$